# If $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is some function, and $g(r,\theta)=(r\cos{\theta},r\sin{\theta})$, compute the matrix $Dh_{g(r,\theta)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The question says to express $Dh_{g(r,\theta)}$ only in terms of $r$, $\theta$, and the two entries of $D(h\circ G)_{(r,\theta)}$, but I'm not really sure how. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have $h(x,y)$ and so $h(g(r,\theta)) = h(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$. Let $g = g(r, \theta)$. Therefore, by chain rule we have;

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial r} = \begin{bmatrix} h_x(g) \ h_y(g) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta \\  \sin \theta \end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \  \frac{\partial h}{\partial \theta} = \begin{bmatrix} h_x(g) \ h_y(g) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -r\sin \theta \\ \ \ r\cos \theta \end{bmatrix} $$

Notice that since we take the evaluations of $h_x, h_y$ at $g$, then whatever function $h$ may be, those things will be in terms of $r, \theta$.

$$Dh_{g(r, \theta)} = \begin{bmatrix} h_x(g) \cos \theta + h_y(g) \sin \theta \\ \\ h_x(g)(-r \sin \theta) + h_y(g) (r \cos \theta)\end{bmatrix}$$